# Windows gVim 7.3 is creating unexpected folders when opening a file

Tags: windows, vim, windows-7

My setup is:

1. Windows7 SP1 (Enterprise)
2. gVim 7.3

Whenever I open a file, Gvim will create 2 folders in the same folder as the file is located. The folders' names are `Files` and `(x86)`. This only started happening recently. Any idea what could be causing this?

My `_vimrc` files is as follows

```
set nocompatible
source $VIMRUNTIME/vimrc_example.vim
behave xterm
set ic
set nu
set ai
set noswapfile
set nobackup
source $VIMRUNTIME/colors/darkblue.vim
set expandtab           " expand tabs
set shiftwidth=3 
set softtabstop=3
set ruler       " show the cursor position all the time

source $VIMRUNTIME/plugin/linuxsty.vim
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have any plugins installed? Then try running without them (`--noplugin` argument), also try a plain Vim `gvim -N -u NONE`.

It looks like some plugin doesn't do proper quoting of an argument.

You can capture a full log of a Vim session with `vim -V20vimlog`. After quitting Vim, examine the `vimlog` log file for suspect commands.

Comment: `--noplugin` showed that the issue was with a pluging. vimlog did the trick